# Is Apple's documentation on ARCamera.transform orientation backwards?

Tags: documentation, arkit, uiinterfaceorientation, uideviceorientation, arcamera

I'm having a hard time grasping the Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/2866108-transform) regarding the `ARCamera.transform`.

Excerpt:

> In camera space, the x-axis points to the right when the device is in UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight orientation—that is, the x-axis always points along the long axis of the device, from the front-facing camera toward the Home button.

Okay, so the positive x-axis points to the right, towards the Home button, when we are in landscape right...

But the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uideviceorientation/uideviceorientationlandscaperight) for `UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight` says:

> The device is in landscape mode, with the device held upright and the home button on the left side.

So in landscape right, the Home button is on the left.  This contradicts the statement that the Home button and positive x-axis point to the right.

What am I missing?  Are the docs wrong?  Do they intend to reference the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiinterfaceorientation/landscaperight) of  `UIInterfaceOrienation.landscapeRight`?

Comment: Apple documentation is a joke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like they've fixed their [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiinterfaceorientation/landscaperight) for `UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight`:

> The device is in landscape mode, with the device held upright and the Home button on the right side.